# Puppet container wont start automatically

Tags: docker, puppet

So I have created a puppet container for a certificate authority.  It works, but does not start correctly.  Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:6
RUN yum update -y
RUN rpm -ivh http://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-6.noarch.rpm
RUN yum install -y ruby puppet-server  
ADD puppet.conf /etc/puppet/puppet.conf

VOLUME ["/var/lib/puppet/ssl/"]
EXPOSE 9140

#NOTHING BELOW THIS COMMENT RUNS
RUN puppet master --verbose 

CMD service puppetmaster start
CMD chkconfig puppetmaster on
CMD []
```

I can then start the container with the following run(note that I named the image ca-puppet):

```
docker run -d -p 9140:9140 -it --name ca-puppet \
-v /puppet-host/ssl:/var/lib/puppet/ssl \
ca-puppet bash
```

The issue is that I need to `docker exec` into the container and run the following commands to get it started and create the ca certificates in its ssl directory:

```
puppet master --verbose 
service puppetmaster start
chkconfig puppetmaster on
```

I have a feeling I should be using some other Docker file commands to run the last 3 commands.  What should that be?

Answer (score 1):

> There can only be one CMD instruction in a Dockerfile. If you list
>   more than one CMD then only the last CMD will take effect.

also

> If the user specifies arguments to docker run then they will override
>   the default specified in CMD.

However, using the default process manager (e.g., SysV, systemd, etc) in Docker for most mainstream distros can cause problems (without making a lot of modifications). You generally don't need it, however -- particularly if you're only running one application (as is often considered best practice). In a Docker container, you generally want your primary application to be the first process (PID 1).

You can do this by not daemonizing puppet and start it as the default container command via something like:

`CMD puppet master --verbose --no-daemonize`

And use the Docker host to manage it (via `restart` policy, etc.).